# problem with open jpa

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I am getting following error on console when using open jpa.What may be the possible cause?I cant post the code as its against my company policies.

```
[12/31/10 14:54:13:279 GMT+05:30] 00000063 MetaData      W   CWWJP9991W: openjpa.MetaData: Warn: OpenJPA cannot map field "abc.xyz" efficiently.  It is of an unsupported type. The field value will be serialized to a BLOB by default.
[12/31/10 14:54:13:295 GMT+05:30] 00000063 MetaData      W   CWWJP9991W: openjpa.MetaData: Warn: The class "pqr.xyz" listed in the openjpa.MetaDataFactory configuration property could not be loaded; ignoring.
[12/31/10 14:54:13:295 GMT+05:30] 00000063 MetaData      W   CWWJP9991W: openjpa.MetaData: Warn: OpenJPA cannot map field "pqr.xyz" efficiently.  It is of an unsupported type. The field value will be serialized to a BLOB by default.

 Failed to create Bundle in DB:
                                 <openjpa-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:778978M-OPENJPA-975 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Field "abc.xyz" cannot declare that it is mapped by another field. Its mapping strategy (org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.HandlerFieldStrategy) does not support mapping by another field.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.AbstractFieldStrategy.assertNotMappedBy(AbstractFieldStrategy.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.HandlerFieldStrategy.map(HandlerFieldStrategy.java:71)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.setStrategy(FieldMapping.java:121)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.RuntimeStrategyInstaller.installStrategy(RuntimeStrategyInstaller.java:80)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolveMapping(FieldMapping.java:454)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolve(FieldMapping.java:419)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.resolveNonRelationMappings(ClassMapping.java:879)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.prepareMapping(MappingRepository.java:339)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.preMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:662)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:549)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:308)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:363)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.classForName(QueryImpl.java:1569)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery$1.classForName(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:108)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getClassMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:168)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.resolveClassMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:139)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:225)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateMetaData(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:195)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.getCandidateType(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder.access$600(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:69)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLExpressionBuilder$ParsedJPQL.populate(JPQLExpressionBuilder.java:1756)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.populate(JPQLParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.populateFromCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:658)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:639)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:605)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:667)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compile(QueryImpl.java:574)
    at com.xyz.ws.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:105)
    at com.xyz.ws.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:37)
    at com.xyz.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEmInvocation.createNamedQuery(JPATxEmInvocation.java:116)
    at com.xyz.ws.jpa.management.JPAEntityManager.createNamedQuery(JPAEntityManager.java:302)
```

Comment: I'd start by figuring out why pqr.xyz can't be loaded. Maybe your environment is missing some dependencies; maybe the class name is spelled wrong somewhere; maybe the classloading environment that OpenJPA is running within is not appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

I just solved an error like this. The error was quite misleading. The problem was I forgot to put the entity into the `persistence.xml` file.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem.

The message is not clear!

**What solved my problem** was implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()` in the **entity object** and its **pk object**.

Also see if the `class` is **declared inside** the `persistence.xml`

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess (best I can do without seeing code) that you have a relationship to another class that you have failed to annotate with @ManyToOne, @OneToMany or similar.